# How do I print a string in Emacs lisp with ielm?

Tags: emacs, elisp, read-eval-print-loop

I'd like to print a string in ielm. I don't want to print the printed representation, I want the string itself. I'd like this result:

```
ELISP> (some-unknown-function "a\nb\n")
a
b
ELISP>
```

I can't see any way to do this. The obvious functions are `print` and `princ`, but these give me the printable representation:

```
ELISP> (print "* first\n* second\n* third\n")
"* first\n* second\n* third\n"
```

I've played with `pp` and `pp-escape-newlines`, but these still escape other characters:

```
ELISP> (setq pp-escape-newlines nil)
nil
ELISP> (pp "a\n")
"\"a
\""
```

Is this possible? For inspecting large strings, `message` doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about inserting directly into the buffer?

```
(defun p (x) (move-end-of-line 0) (insert (format "\n%s" x)))
```

That gets you:

```
ELISP> (p "a\nb\n")
a
b

nil
ELISP>
```

EDIT: Use `format` to be able to print things other than strings.

Comment: Clever hack, I like it! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
;;; Commentary:

;; Provides a nice interface to evaluating Emacs Lisp expressions.
;; Input is handled by the comint package, and output is passed
;; through the pretty-printer.
```

IELM uses `(pp-to-string ielm-result)` (so binding `pp-escape-newlines` has an effect in general), but if you want to bypass `pp` altogether then IELM doesn't provide for that, so I suspect Sean's answer is your best option.

```
ELISP> (setq pp-escape-newlines nil)
nil
ELISP> "foo\nbar"
"foo
bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sean's answer is correct if you want to display the string as part of your session.

However, you say you want to inspect large strings. An alternative approach would be to put the string in a separate window. You could use [`with-output-to-temp-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Temporary-Displays.html) to do this. For instance:

```
(with-output-to-temp-buffer "*string-inspector*"
  (print "Hello, world!")
  nil)
```

A new window will pop up (or if it already exists, its output will be changed). It's in Help mode, so it's readonly and can be closed with <kbd>q</kbd>.

If you want to do some more sophisticated stuff in your output buffer you could use [`with-temp-buffer-window`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Temporary-Displays.html) instead, like so:

```
(with-temp-buffer-window "*string-inspector*"
                         #'temp-buffer-show-function
                         nil
  (insert "hello, world!!"))
```